# Sharing fetched data between components in urql

Tags: reactjs, urql

I want to share state fetched from the backend between components, just like I would using redux. Specifically, once a user is logging in, the response he gets includes settings, notifications and recent posts. How do I distribute those across components using urql? I want to avoid fetching all this data in separate requests

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found on github urql has no local state (like apollo has `apollo-link-state`), but only [cache](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/graphcache/).

You could either cache the data or:

- use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- store the data in localstorage

Comment: I don't want to use local state though. I want to pass remote data between components. Although I'm not sure if that actually makes a difference